# Why is it compiling file twice

Tags: gnu-make

I have a makefile

```
jumbo: objs/jumbo.o  objs/utils.o

objs/%.o: %.C
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

The result of the compile

```
g++     jumbo.C objs/jumbo.o objs/utils.o   -o jumbo
objs/jumbo.o:jumbo.C:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `main'
/tmp/ccwEFt9o.o:jumbo.C:(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [<builtin>: server] Error 1
```

if I replace the definition of jumbo

```
jumbo: jumbo.C objs/utils.o
```

the problem goes away but the object file is not put away in the objs directory

And I don't know whether it is recompiling jumbo or not when it should only be relinking

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined any recipe for building the target `jumbo`.  Because of that, make looks for a built-in rule and there is one that knows how to build a file `X` from a file `X.C`.  Make looks at the directory and lo and behold, there's an `X.C` (`jumbo.C`) that exists, so make chooses to use that built-in rule.  The built-in rule is:

```
%: %.C
        $(LINK.C) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```

so, since `jumbo` depends on `objs/jumbo.` and `objs/utils.o` directory plus the `jumbo.C` from the default implicit rule, you get all three on the command line.

To fix this just define your own recipe for creating `jumbo`:

```
jumbo: objs/jumbo.o  objs/utils.o
        $(LINK.C) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```